# How do I interpret and relate the elements in bold in the following sentence?

Tags: interpretation, literature

I am having difficulty parsing the sentence below and understanding its meaning. Is the narrator saying that he doesn’t understand “practical pain” like hunger, or the more extreme pains like his own 10 examples? Or both?

I am also confused about what phrases go together. I think that: 最も強い痛苦 ＝ 「自分の例の十個の禍いなどの痛苦、吹っ飛んでしまう程の痛苦、地獄なのかもしれない痛苦」(全て) ＝ それは（わからない）
Is this correct?

I also don’t understand what それこそ is doing in this sentence. Is it equating the [プラクテカルな苦しみ] with the ones above? I.e. that the [プラクテカルな苦しみ] are precisely [それこそ] the strongest pains?

> 「つまり、わからないのです。隣人の苦しみの性質、程度が、まるで見当つかないのです。プラクテカルな苦しみ、ただ、めしを食えたらそれで解決できる苦しみ、しかし、**それこそ**最も強い痛苦で、自分の例の十個の禍いなど、**吹っ飛んでしまうほどの**、**凄惨な阿鼻地獄なのかもしれない**、**それは**、わからない、(しかし、それにしては、よく自殺もせず、発狂もせず、政党を論じ、絶望せず、屈せず生活のたたかいを続けて行ける、苦しくないんじゃないか)？」（人間失格、第一の手記）

**EDIT: made “equation” above clearer**

Comment: Where does the right side of the first equation end?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out; I just edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks so much for including some context and indicating the source of the quotation, rather than just posting the phrase you're asking about! How I wish everyone who posts questions on this site would follow your example.

Comment: @Nanigashi I know what you mean. I’ve seen many questions like that, and it’s frustrating. Even when you want to help, you don’t know where to begin because context is important in most, if not all, cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part means

> プラクテカルな苦しみ ＝ただ、めしを食えたらそれで解決できる苦しみ ＝それ **＝?** 最も強い痛苦で ＝ 自分の例の十個の禍いなど、吹っ飛んでしまうほどの、凄惨な阿鼻地獄

The ? is indicated by なのかもしれない,

しかし、それこそ means *but, precisely that (=hunger) is....* An implicit feeling of the author/protagonist is that hunger is less significant (or lower or mean) as suffering than his own (spiritual?) one because hunger is simply a matter of food.

The following それは、わからない means literally *That, I don't know*. *That* refers to the whole equation, i.e., it expresses he does not know whether the "practical pain" (= hunger) is something greater than his own suffering.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So what he doesn’t understand is not the pain itself, but whether practical pains like hunger are the same or greater than his 10 “hell-like” pains, roughly speaking. 説明をありがとうございました！

Comment: @polygokko, Actually, the narrator is not saying that his own ten misfortunes are "hell-like." Rather, he is saying that for all he knows the "practical pain" of hunger may be the worst pain of all, and may be a hell so horrifying that his own ten misfortunes would seem trivial (more literally, would "blow away") in comparison. (I'm not saying that sundowner's explanation is incorrect, but that it seems you haven't completely understood it. The key is that 自分の例の十個の禍いなど、吹っ飛んでしまうほどの is **modifying** 凄惨な阿鼻地獄. If this remains unclear to you, you might want to post a new question about it.)

Comment: @Nanigashi thanks for the comment. I think you’re right; I almost understand it, but the syntax in the sentence still jars me a bit. The text is probably too advanced for me; 仕方がありませんね。

Comment: @polygokko, it **is** a difficult text; even many Japanese readers find Dazai Osamu's writing abstruse at times. But I think it's great that you're challenging yourself by reading a classic literary novel. You're sure to learn a lot from it, even if you don't completely understand every single sentence.